# Objective-C local notifications firing two times

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I'm using `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application` in my AppDelegate.m file and I'm displaying a notification everyday like this:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application

    {

        UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        UIApplication *myapp = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

       if (hour > 8 && hour < 10)
       {
                    notification.fireDate = [components date];
                    notification.repeatInterval = 0;
                    notification.soundName = @"";
                    notification.alertBody = @"This is an notification!";
                    [myapp scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
       }
    }
```

Everything works fine except when notification is fired and app closed after user opens an app and than close it notification will fire again. Is there some method different than `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application`(alert must show even when app is closed completely [killed with task manager]) or I need to solve it with some code.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems here you never remove local notifications, so if you intend on firing one per day and the user minimizes your app twice in one day you'll end up scheduling two local notifications. Take a look at [cancelLocalNotification: and cancelAllLocalNotifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW86)

Comment: Every time you schedule a notification it remains scheduled until you cancel it (or it expires).  If you schedule 5 you will get 5 notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your app has been closed completely there is nothing more you can do. The method you're using is correct for when the app enters the background. `applicationWillTerminate` is called just before the app is terminated. After that point, that's it. No more.

Comment: But I have some apps on my phone that are closed completely(double tap on home button, swipe up) and they still send me notifications, like Yahoo weather app, or some games, how is  that possible?

Comment: Those are called Push notifications. They are sent to the phone. When opened, they launch their respective app. https://developer.apple.com/notifications/

Comment: Is it possible than to make an timer that runs every 30min to display local notification?

Comment: Yes. If the app is still active in the background or foreground. If it has been terminated no. Your code doesn't exist outside of the app.

Comment: So to wrap thing it's not possible to send local notifications to user every day at the same time while app is completely closed? (sorry for all stupid question but I can't believe apple doesn't allow that)

Comment: I can say with absolute certainty, that is not possibly at at all.